# Android Application update component names

Tags: android

I am trying to update an Android application that I launched some time ago.
I understand that I should not change component names ([described here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)). 
In the original Manifest file, I did not set the `android:exported` as false, as I should have for my activities.

Would it be safe to remove some of these activities in the new version (except for maybe, the launcher activity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that must remain unchanged is package id and certificate you sign the app with. Everything else can be safely changed/removed/whatever

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt answer.